# Creating a repeating true/false List in scala

Tags: scala

I want to generate a Seq/List of true/false values which I can zip with some input in order to do the equivalent of checking whether a for loop index is odd/even.

Is there a better way than

```
input.zip((1 to n).map(_ % 2 == 0))
```

or

```
input.zip(List.tabulate(n)(_ % 2 != 0))
```

I would have thought something like `(true, false).repeat(n/2)` is more obvious

Comment: `(true, false).repeat(n/2)` would look like trouble to me: if `n` is odd, you'd have a missing element at the end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [@DaveGriffith's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132528/creating-a-repeating-true-false-list-in-scala#comment11478599_9132935):

```
input.zip(Stream.iterate(false)(!_))
```

Or, if you use this pattern in several places:

```
def falseTrueStream = Stream.iterate(false)(!_)

input.zip(falseTrueStream)
```

This has the distinct advantage of not needing to specify the size of the false-true list.

***Edit:***

Of course, `def falseTrueStream` creates the stream of `true`/`false` objects every time you use it, and as [@DanielCSobral](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53013/daniel-c-sobral) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132528/creating-a-repeating-true-false-list-in-scala?answertab=votes#comment11485688_9133674), making it a `val` will cause the objects to be held in memory (until the program ends if the `val` is on an `object`).

If you're slightly evil and want to prematurely optimize it, you can build the `Stream` objects yourself.

```
object TrueFalseStream extends Stream[Boolean] {
  val tailDefined = true

  override val isEmpty = false

  override val head = true

  override val tail = FalseTrueStream
}

object FalseTrueStream extends Stream[Boolean] {
  val tailDefined = true

  override val isEmpty = false

  override val head = false

  override val tail = TrueFalseStream
}
```

Comment: Please, `def falseTrueStream` instead of `val`, or you might get a memory leak.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a list of alternating true/false of size n:

```
List.iterate(false, n)(!_)
```

So then you could do:

```
val input = List("a", "b", "c", "d")
input.zip(List.iterate(false, input.length)(!_))
//List[(java.lang.String, Boolean)] = List((a,false), (b,true), (c,false), (d,true))
```

Comment: Nice.  Didn't know List had an iterate method, so I was going to suggest the Stream.iterate(false)(!_).take(n).toList as a bit of a joke.

Comment: @DaveGriffith Actually, `Stream.iterate` isn't such a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

There's a very useful function in Haskell - `cycle` - which is useful for such purposes:

```
haskell> zip [1..7] $ cycle [True, False]
[(1,True),(2,False),(3,True),(4,False),(5,True),(6,False),(7,True)]
```

For some reason, Scala standard library doesn't have it. You can define it on your own, and then use it.

```
scala> def cycle[A](s: Stream[A]): Stream[A] = Stream.continually(s).flatten
cycle: [A](s: Stream[A])Stream[A]

scala> (1 to 7) zip cycle(Stream(true, false))
res13: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Int, Boolean)] = Vector((1,true), (2,false), (3,true), (4,false), (5,true), (6,false), (7,true))
```

Comment: Note that this approach (`Stream.continually(...).flatten`) produces a repeating list with unbounded potential space consumption, not a cyclical one fitting in constant space.

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
input.indices.map(_%2==0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't come up with anything simpler (and this is far from simple):

```
(for(_ <- 1 to n/2) yield List(true, false)).flatten
```

and:

```
(1 to n/2).foldLeft(List[Boolean]()) {(cur,_) => List(true, false) ++ cur}
```

Watch for odd `n`!

However based on your requirements it looks like you might want to have something *lazy*:

```
def oddEven(init: Boolean): Stream[Boolean] = Stream.cons(init, oddEven(!init))
```

...and it never ends (try: `oddEven(true) foreach println`). Now you can take as much as you want:

```
oddEven(true).take(10).toList
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...in order to do the equivalent of checking whether a for loop index is odd/even.

I'm ignoring your specific request, and addressing your main concern in a different way.
You can make your own control function, like so:

```
def for2[A,B](xs: List[A])(f: A => Unit, g: A => Unit): Unit = xs match {
    case (y :: ys) => {
      f(y)
      for2(ys)(g, f)
    }
    case _ => Unit
}
```

Testing

```
> for2(List(0,1,2,3,4,5))((x) => println("E: " + x), (x) => println("O: " + x))
E: 0
O: 1
E: 2
O: 3
E: 4
O: 5
```